# Sorting a hash of arrays looking up the comparisons in another hash in Perl

Tags: perl, sorting, hash

Say I want sort a hash of arrays (`%hash`) by looking up the comparisons in another hash (`%comparator`):

I thought the following would work, but it didn't.

```
for ($bin_ix=1; $bin_ix<scalar(keys(%cluster_bins)); $bin_ix++) {    
   $hash{$bin_ix} = sort {$comparator{$a} <=> $comparator{$b} $hash{$bin_ix}};
}
```

It complains with: `Missing operator before %hash`. What am I missing?

Comment: You might consider using a simpler syntax for your for loop: `for my $bin_ix (1 .. keys %cluster_bins)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it says

```
Scalar found where operator expected at -e line 2, near "} $hash"
        (Missing operator before  $hash?)
```

It's complaining about your misplaced `}`, but there's a second problem: `$hash{$bin_ix}` is merely a reference to the array, not an array. You want

```
@{ $hash{$bin_ix} } =
   sort { $comparator{$a} <=> $comparator{$b} }
      @{ $hash{$bin_ix} };
```

Answer (score 2):

Ikegami has already answered your direct question, but I'd like to note that, if you indeed want to sort *all* the arrays in `%hash`, a simpler way to write your loop would be:

```
foreach my $array ( values %hash ) {
    @$array = sort { $comparator{$a} <=> $comparator{$b} } @$array;
}
```

Even if you indeed only want to sort the arrays for the keys from `1` to `scalar keys %cluster_bins`, TLP's suggestion would still be cleaner:

```
foreach my $bin_idx ( 1 .. keys %cluster_bins ) {
    my $array = $hash{ $bin_idx };
    @$array = sort { $comparator{$a} <=> $comparator{$b} } @$array;
}
```